# How to load test a JavaScript/AngularJS app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, load, performance-testing

I have a JavaScript/AngularJS app, which connects with a server via websockets.

Is there an easy way for a load test? For example, I would like to see what happens when the app is called 100x at the same time (so there are 100 connections to the webserver).

Is there a simple way to test it? If I need software for this, it should run local, since the app is on my computer.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You would just loadtest the server, by making lots of requests to the static resources and also load test your api. Have a look at [jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

Answer (score 3):

You can try https://github.com/kidk/felt

It uses real browsers to generate load to a website. It is still a young project, but it might be the solution you are looking for.

(This is my personal project)

Answer (score 0):

Fallowing link may helps to you .

https://github.com/observing/thor

Answer (score 0):

The AngularJS crew have developed Protractor for end-to-end testing

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/e2e-testing